# Removing space after a "." in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I searched the site, but could not get a relevant answer. Almost all of them are about removing all the white spaces.
What I need is to remove space or tab just after "."
For Example:

```
I am here. Where are you?
```

The result should be

```
I am here.Where are you?
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through sed,

```
$ echo 'I am here. Where are you?' | sed 's/\.[[:space:]]/./g'
I am here.Where are you?
```

**OR**

```
sed 's/\.[[:blank:]]/./g' file
```

**Explanation:**

- `\.` Matches a literal dot.
- POSIX character class `[[:space:]]` would match all whitespace characters, including line breaks
- POSIX character class `[[:blank:]]` would match all the horizontal spaces.
- Above sed command would replace all the matched characters with `.`, so replacing `.` plus it's following space with dot will give you the desired output.

Comment: Hey Thanks! Can you please explain the regular expression to me?

Comment: A regular expression is something that describes word patterns. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression